# ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose_shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am following the Coursera, Deep Learning course with Andrew Ng for object detection with YOLO algorithm, I am trying to run the algorithm on my PC using Windows and Anaconda Navigator, I installed Keras to run on TensorFlow backend. But when I typed the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
```

It showed me the following:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-0bcaeab92875>", line 2, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..utils.generic_utils import transpose_shape

ImportError: cannot import name 'transpose_shape'
```

Seems like it has a problem with this line in the tensorflow_backend.py file:

```
from ..utils.generic_utils import transpose_shape
```

Help would be much appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: From `TF2.0` onward `keras` are integrated with `tensorflow`. Hence you can import backend module as `from tensorflow.keras import backend as k` and you wont face above issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to uninstall tensorflow and keras and install keras using pip, it also installs tensorflow. It worked for me!!!

Comment: It's weird because my original installation was in an empty environment, but it did solve the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Probably a misconfiguration of the installed packages:

```
pip uninstall -y tensorflow keras tf-nightly keras-nightly
```

and then:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried re-install of existing versions, didnt work.

I'm running windows 10, Python 3.7.5  64 bit version

What worked for me - installing Keras 2.3.1, Tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use from tensorflow.keras import backend as K instead of from keras import backend as K.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.keras import
```

Because keras has been owned by tensorflow.